# when i use onConfiguarionchange app is using wrong string resouce,why this happen?

Tags: android, configuration, local

i have an app which support more than one language and i override onConfigurationChanged wrong string file is loaded

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    LocaleHelper.setLocale(this);
    Utils.Log(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged: " +getClass().getName()+" "+newConfig.locale.getLanguage());
}
```

Comment: Make sure you correctly configure the manifest file to make it work for you https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes

Comment: when,i removed onConfigurationChanged app works well,but i still don't know what cause the problem which is very important for future debug